# Strange things SSIS does on the data journey

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In an execute sql task. I have a column called LastEditedBY which is varchar in Source System 1. In the Execute Sql Task, all I do is:

```
Select cast ( LastEditedBy as INT) from Table1
```

All the values that are null at the moment. I then store it in a variable of type INT called LastEditedBy.

I then run a stored procedure in a second Execute Sql Task to insert into Source System 2, which requires the input to be of a data type INT.

Watching in the SSIS via the Watch Window, It takes a null and sets the variable to 0 instead of '', empty string.

Is this a defect? How can I ensure that instead of getting a 0 for nulls, I get a ''?

Comment: SELECT cast(Null as INT) would still return NULL, can you check your variable in SSIS? maybe the default is set to 0

Comment: An int-type variable cannot contain an empty string under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT variables in SSIS will convert NULLs to Zeros, what I can recommend in your case is to declare the variable as a string and do the conversion to INT in a later stage, probably in your SP.